# Chart path animation

Tags: ios, swift, charts, core-animation

I try to implement animation for changing chart data. I use the code below:

```
if let chartLayer = chartLayers[chartName], chartLayer.superlayer != nil {
                let animation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "path")

                animation.fromValue = chartLayer.path
                animation.toValue = path.cgPath
                animation.duration = 0.2

                animation.delegate = self
                chartLayer.path = path.cgPath
                self.isAnimated = true
                chartLayer.add(animation, forKey: "path")
            } else {
                let chartLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                chartLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
                chartLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                chartLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.init(hexFromString: chartData.colors[yData.key] ?? "").cgColor
                chartLayer.path = path.cgPath
                layer.addSublayer(chartLayer)
                chartLayers[chartName] = chartLayer
            }
```

Now it looks fine for changing data at the right, but at the left it looks weird. Can somebody give me advice what I do wrong?

UPDATE: I expect that changing data at the left will look the same as at the right (I mean smooth changing scale and adding more lines)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to see? It looks good to me.

Comment: @Magnas I updated question

Comment: The animation is perfectly fine, your right data set has max y value and when you change your left bar pos then it doesn't zoom but when you move your right the max value changes and thus zooms accordingly. So you should some how try to fix your y axis, How? don't know